# How to do an insert and a select in the same PHP file with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I really don't want to create a file for the insert and another file for the select and so, there is an attribute or something that i cant use to difference the actions in my file, this is my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'functions/actions.php', //Here is where i think i cannot difference actions
    dataType: 'json',
    data: serializedData
})
```

I usually do this only in PHP setting an action like this in the form:

```
<form action="funciones/actions.php?do=newcall" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And handle it in PHP with an `if` statement:

```
if(isset($_GET["do"]) && $_GET["do"]!=""){
    $action = $_GET["do"];
    if($action=="new"){
```

There is a similiar way to handle the actions like that using ajax? Or some way that not require creating a .php for select and other for insert.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't. The type of request is important. I'd use POST for an insert and GET for a request. If you want to request what you've just inserted then use the ajax success response by all means in the same call as the POST. Just my two cents, there's lots of different combinations.

Comment: Get it, i wasn't thinking too clear to be honest, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use the same php script to handle many different actions - dependant upon method and/or other request parameters. As an example some pseudo dummy code

```
<?php

    /* functions/actions.php */

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['action'] ) ){
            switch( $_POST['action'] ){
                case 'add-gerbil':$sql='insert gerbil into snake';break;
                case 'del-gerbil':$sql='delete gerbil from snake';break;
            }
            $db->query($sql);
        }
        exit();
    }

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' ){
        if( !empty( $_GET['action'] ) ){
            switch( $_GET['action'] ){
                case 'get-gerbil': $sql='select gerbil from snake';
                case 'get-snake': $sql='select snake';
            }
            $db->query($sql);
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Each block of code is targetable by either POST or GET and the individul tasks that can be run are defined by whatever parameter ( in this case `action` ) is defined in the ajax call.

So you could do

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'functions/actions.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'action':'add-gerbil', 'name':'tito', 'color':'green' }
})
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'functions/actions.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'action':'get-gerbil', 'name':'tito' }
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in comments - OP should accept

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much thats exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: The only thing i have to research was that i need to code with this format: data: serializedData + '&action=' + 'insertslides'; in order to mantain the data i was trying to send, problem solved!